# MVC Form in partial view submitting null

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I have a form in a partial view that is diplaying the data i want properly. However when the form is submitted the model thats passed to the controller is null. Im not sure if it because it is in a partial view or not, everything appears to be right to me.

Partial View

```
    @model CustomerPickUp.Web.Models.SalesOrderModel
    <h3 id="resultHeader">Search Results</h3>
    <div id="resultsContainer">
    <div id="container">
        <table class="resultTable">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateQueue", "Order", FormMethod.Post, new {id = "updateQueueForm"}))
            {
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
                for (var i = 0; i < Model.SalesOrderList.Count(); i++)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(it => Model.SalesOrderList[i].IsSelected)
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align: right;">
                            @Html.Label("CustomerName", "Customer Name: ")
                            <br/>
                            @Html.Label("OrderNumber", "Order Number: ")
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align: left;">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(it => Model.SalesOrderList[i].CustomerName)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(it => Model.SalesOrderList[i].CustomerName)
                            <br/>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(it => Model.SalesOrderList[i].OrderNumber)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(it => Model.SalesOrderList[i].OrderNumber)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            }
        </table>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="searchTypeSelection">

            @(Html.Kendo().Button()
          .Name("saveButton")
          .Content("Add to Queue")
          .HtmlAttributes(new {@class = "medium-btn"})
          .Events(e => e.Click("save_Clicked"))
          )
</div>
```

Controller

```
    public ActionResult UpdateQueue(SalesOrderModel SALESorder)
        {
            if (SALESorder.SalesOrderList != null)
            {
                foreach (SalesOrder item in SALESorder.SalesOrderList)
                {
                    if (item.IsSelected)
                    {
                        AddToOrderQueue(item);
                    }
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Orders");
        }
```

Main View

```
    @{
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_CurrentQueueLayout.cshtml";
    }
    <div id="searchControls">
        @using (Ajax.BeginForm("ProcessSearch", "Search", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "resultSection" }, new { id = "searchForm", @class = "pure-Form" }))
    {
        <div class="searchTypeSelection">
            @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
                  .Name("searchOption")
                  .DataTextField("Text")
                  .OptionLabel("Search By...")
                  .DataValueField("Value")
                  .BindTo(new List<SelectListItem>()
                  {

                      new SelectListItem()
                      {
                          Text = "SO Number",
                          Value = "2"
                      },
                      new SelectListItem()
                      {
                          Text = "Phone Number",
                          Value = "1"
                      }
                  })

            )
            <br />
            <br />
            <input type="text" id="searchString" name="searchString" disabled="disabled" />


            @(Html.Kendo().Button()
                  .Name("searchButton")
                  .Content("Search")
                  .Events(e => e.Click("search_clicked"))
                  .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "medium-btn" })
            )
        </div>

    }
</div>
<div id="resultSection">


</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
        //clear all fields
        $("#searchString").val("");
        $("#searchString").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    });
    $("#searchOption").change(function () {
        var dropdownlist = $("#searchOption").data("kendoDropDownList");
        var index = parseInt($("#searchOption").val());
        alert(index);
        if (dropdownlist.value() == 2) {
            $("#searchString").inputmask("************");
            $("#searchString").val("");
            $("#searchString").removeAttr("disabled");
        } else if (dropdownlist.value() == 1) {
            $("#searchString").inputmask("999-999-9999");
            $("#searchString").removeAttr("disabled");
            $("#searchString").val("");
        } else {
            $("#searchString").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $("#searchButton").addClass("mobileButtonDisabled");
        }
    });

    $('#searchString').on('input', function () {
        var maskedtextbox = $("#searchString").val();
        var dropdownlist = $("#searchOption").data("kendoDropDownList");

        if ((dropdownlist.value() == 1 || dropdownlist.value() == 2) && maskedtextbox != "") {
            $("#searchButton").removeClass("mobileButtonDisabled");
        } else {
            $("#searchButton").addClass("mobileButtonDisabled");
        }
    });

    function search_clicked(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#searchForm").submit();
    };

    function save_Clicked(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#updateQueueForm").submit();
    };
</script>
```

**UPDATE**

I changed the signature of that action, but that didnt change anything. After looking at the generated HTML i noticed that my elements arent being rendered in the form. Any ideas on why?

```
 <form id="updateQueueForm" method="post" action="/Order/UpdateQueue">  </form>
 <tbody>
 <tr>
<td>
<td style="text-align: right;">
<td style="text-align: left;">
<td>
<td style="text-align: right;">
<td style="text-align: left;">
```

Comment: The save button should be in the form. It has no context.

Comment: I am manually calling the form to submit, which is working. The controller action is being hit, just null passed.

Comment: function save_Clicked(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#updateQueueForm").submit();
    };

Comment: Put all relevant code in the question.

Comment: I updated the code to include the main view and the javascript. I had this code working before, the only change i can think of is that i am using a partial view. If i only use a displayfor, no value is submitted for that field when you submit the form.

Comment: is `ProcessSearch` including in your partial view? I don't see anything in your MainView that would include PartialView.

Comment: Yes, it is in there, as well as quite a few other methods. I excluded them for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

you using wrong code in partial view controller

```
public PartialViewResult UpdateQueue(SalesOrderModel SALESorder)
       {
         //
       }
```

Also not sure about your button best to use html submit button

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the table element i had the form wrapped in was the cause. I am certain i have done this before, but its better to do it the right way anyway. Thanks for your help, heres what i ended up changing.

```
  <div id="container">
    <div class="table">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateQueue", "Order", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "updateQueueForm", @class = "row" }))
        {
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
            for (var i = 0; i < Model.SalesOrderList.Count(); i++)
            {
                <div class="cell">

                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(it => Model.SalesOrderList[i].IsSelected)
                </div>

                <div class="cell" style="text-align: right;">
                    @Html.Label("CustomerName", "Customer Name: ")
                    <br />
                    @Html.Label("OrderNumber", "Order Number: ")

                </div>

                <div class="cell" style="text-align: left;">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(it => Model.SalesOrderList[i].CustomerName)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(it => Model.SalesOrderList[i].CustomerName)
                    <br />
                    @Html.DisplayFor(it => Model.SalesOrderList[i].OrderNumber)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(it => Model.SalesOrderList[i].OrderNumber)

                </div>
            }
        }
    </div>
</div>
```